# Suggestions for cross layer builder pattern in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, n-tier-architecture

I have an n-tired application with MVC as the presentation. The view is a form which operates like a wizard. When the user clicks next on each wizard step, I'd like the information collected from the step to be processed in the service layer.

What I have set up at the moment is:

1. User submits the current step in **View**
2. **Controller** takes in the current view's model
3. Convert the model to a DTO using **AutoMapper**
4. Pass the DTO into the service method to perform the necessary processing on the DTO
5. Convert the DTO back into it's view model Redirect to next step.

Code looks similar to:

```
public DemoController
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public DemoController(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Next(ViewModel model, int value)
    {
        var dto = Mapper.Map<DTO>(model);
        _service.ProcessNext(dto, value);
        model = Mapper.Map<ViewModel>(dto);
        return RedirectToAction("NextStepAfterThis");
    }  
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this result?

Comment: Are you asking for a review?  Or do you have a particular issue with the current pattern?

Comment: I used very similar approach for similar task with wizard and it works fine. Though I'm not sure if there are some best-practices here.

Comment: The more elegant way would be to use ajax and create a SPA just for this wizard inside of your app. That being said, your approach is pretty standard.

Comment: @DavinTryon Both really, I'm curious to see if there are different solutions. My problem with this approach is just the amount of steps required to put it together. Mapping the model back and forth and serializing the model on the page is tedious.

Comment: When using N-Tier, especially with SOA like this, you are going to have to map between the different layers/dtos.  You can keep your controller small by doing the mapping in a static explicit operator in one of your entities, so in your controller you see no mapping code, but casting calls which are clearer in their intent, how it does it is down the static explicit. Other than that, welcome to the world of N-Tier/SOA